# Init Method in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I've been developing out some angular controllers and I've been coming up on a pattern that I'm not too big of a fan of.  Given the following:

```
 app.controller('RecordCtrl', ['$scope', function AppBuilderCtrl($scope) {

      // do lots of object initing here ...
     $scope.model = { ... };
     $scope.defs = $scope.buildDefs($scope.model);

     // lots of functions on scope ...
     $scope.defs = function(model) { ... };
 });
```

The `defs` throws undefined ( duh its not defined until after ) but then I end up moving a lot of my init code to the bottom which doesn't seem that great.  I guess I could do something like:

```
 // top of controller
 init = function(){ ... }

 // all my methods here

init();
```

but thats eh too.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mixed something up in your post - the problem you described isn't evident in the code. Anyway, I think I get what you're saying. The solution is **services**. You shouldn't be running functions in your controller. The controller is just for wiring data to the view. So, if you needed to create something via a function, that function is contained in a service that you pass to the controller, not in the controller itself.

[Here's an example (click for live demo).](http://jsbin.com/efidIto/1/edit)

```
<p>{{foo.bar}}</p> <!-- 123 -->
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('myService', function() {
  var myService = { //put your methods in services like this
    create: function() {
      return {
        bar: '123' 
      };
    }
  };
  return myService;
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService) { //pass the service in
  $scope.foo = myService.create(); //method is available!
  console.log($scope.foo);
});
```

Comment: I see ... I was under the impression services were used more for AJAX requests and helper methods for the models returned from the.

Comment: @amcdnl yeah, they're used for that also, but not exclusively. "Angular services are singletons objects or functions that carry out specific tasks common to web apps." according to http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services